Email for subdomain going to main domain server
I have a main domain at example.com, which is set up so that emails to user@example.com go to a MS Outlook account (as desired). I also have subdomain.example.com and want emails sent to user@subdomain.example.com get delivered to AWS SES.
DNS records including all MX records and the only A record for the main domain or this subdomain look like this:



Type
Record Name
Record Value




example.com
A
accthash.cloudfront.net


example.com
MX
10 example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com


subdomain.example.com
MX
0 inbound-smtp.my-aws-region.amazonaws.com


mail.subdomain.example.com
MX
20 feedback-smtp.my-aws-region.amazonses.com



The server name in the middle MX row is a value for the appropriate region here and the one in the bottom row (probably not needed for this example but included for completeness) is from here for the appropriate region, as a feedback address if mail is sent from subdomain.example.com. The region matches the one where the email receiving rule is set up.
The TTL for each MX record is set to 300 and it's been well over 5 minutes since any update. I've also used Powershell commands like Resolve-DNSName -name subdomain.example.com -Server 8.8.8.8 -Type MX (and without the subdomain) to verify that the records have propagated correctly. Identity verification for the subdomain.example.com identity in SES was previously completed successfully and it's still listed as verified.
Unexpectedly, mail being sent to user@subdomain.example.com is all getting bounced by the Outlook server that should only be processing mail sent to user@example.com, on the correct grounds that it can't find a mailbox/user for user@subdomain.example.com.

If other servers are trying to send mail to the wrong mail server, then there is likely some DNS issue. If it is a DNS issue, I'm not sure how to help you without being able to query the name server.

Are the emails being bounced coming from 365 accounts or from completely external accounts? If the former then could be an issue with your 365 setup (or how it handled subdomains), such that it assumes it is authoritative for the entire domain including subdomains, so tries to deliver locally rather than checking DNS for the relevent MX records.

@KeithLangmead Either external or internal.
